# MediaWiki: How to totally delete a user after creating it (just for practice)?

Tags: mediawiki

MediaWiki: How to totally delete a user after creating it (just for practice)?

I created a user myself in a one-man-editing MediaWiki and I want to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given I only created the user and did nothing else with it afterwards, I was able to fully delete the user from the MediaWiki system this way:

I deleted the (MySQL) database table-row for that user (`TEST_USER`), from these tables:

```
user
recentchanges
logging
```

Then to ensure no data remains for that user in database, I opened the database itself (without choosing a specific table), and ran a search on:

```
TEST_USER
```

Nothing came out in that search.